# TLS Mutual Authentication in Apache - How to get the username of the authenticated user

Tags: apache, authentication, ssl

I have configured TLS Mutual Authentication on my Apache server.
The server now accepts calls only if they specify a certificate that was signed by a CA that I have added in Apache.

Everything works, but I need now to use this configuration to actually authenticate the user: Apache is used to proxy (via ajp) requests to a java application. This java application is expecting the username in a predefined header parameter.

Is there a way to configure Apache to get the username from the certificate and automatically set the expected header parameter?

Comment: The server now accepts calls only if `they` specify a certificate. Who is `they` in your case, another java application? and is it possible to change the behaviour/ logic of the client? Also is it possible to change the behaviour of server `java app is expecting the username in a header.` I'm asking this because instead of passing username in the header, IETF has defined a standard way of passing the client's detail through the proxy to the main server. Reference: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bdc-something-something-certificate-02.html#name-client-cert-http-header-fie

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_ssl's SSLUserName for this, or mod_auth_basics AuthBasicFake.

I never liked the latter because instead of just acting as authentication provider it makes you set a dummy password then let a real authentication module validate it.

Another option is this third-party module which like a certificate-specific AuthBasicFake without the password stuff:
https://github.com/covener/apache-modules/blob/master/mod_authn_cert.c